# Postgresql: Кэширование результата запроса view на случай, если базовая таблица пустая

Tags: sql, postgresql, кэширование, view

У меня есть view. Возможна ситуация, когда таблица(назовем ее базовой) на основании, которой строится view будет пустой.

В этот момент базовая таблица пересчитывается и перезаполняется. Необходимо в этом случае, чтобы View возвращала таблицу построенную на основе старых данных, пока базовая таблица не будет заполненная новыми данными.

Есть ли какие-то варианты решения такой задачи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пересчитывайте таблицу в транзакции.

Всё, все другие читатели будут работать со старыми данными, пока вы не закоммитите транзакцию, в которой пересчитываете данные.

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы таблица была доступна для чтения во время выполнения транзакции? Я поставил connection.setAutoCommit(false) и пока я не выполню rollback или commit любые запросы к таблице висят и не выполняются. Результат получается сразу после выполнения выше указанных команд.

Comment: внимательно посмотреть на то, что именно вы делаете в транзакции. Вероятно обнаружится что-то, требующее access exclusive.

Comment: Проблема была в том, что вместо DELETE FROM использовалось TRUNCATE, который блокирует таблицу на любые обращения. DELETE же оставляет таблицу доступной для чтения. Спасибо, отличное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Материализованные представления решают эту задачу.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2d636c68ff66cd0629f6996bd6df2355)

Соответственно: создаётся обычное представление, и вся работа с таблицей строится только через него. Процедура, которая пересчитывает и перезаполняет базовую таблицу, пересоздаёт вместо обычного представления материализованное, затем обновляет базовую таблицу, после чего опять меняет представление - обратно на обычное.

Насколько это применимо в Вашей ситуации - разбирайтесь самостоятельно. И надо понимать, что это двойной расход пространства. Ну и попытки изменения данных базовой таблицы через представление - за свой счёт.